# Como remover eventos associados a elementos via ".on('acao'"

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um modal do `bootstrap` que utilizo para realizar o cadastro/login `cadastroModal`, mas ao finalizar o pedido, estou reaproveitando ele para solicitar o login e para isso adicionei um evento no `onHiden`, mas não consigo removê-lo depois da chamada, para que ele volte a abrir a tela de finalização de pedido.

Se o usuário clica para fechar o pedido e cancela a tela de login, se ele fizer o login normalmente ele continua disparando o evento

### Associação do evento

```
self.closeOrder = function () {
    if (!self.hasLoggedUser()) {
        $('#carrinhoModal').modal('hide');
        $('#cadastroModal').modal('show');
        $('#cadastroModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            // retorna ao comportamento anterior, só precisávamos agora
            $('#cadastroModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {});
            if (self.hasLoggedUser()) {
                $('#pedidoModal').modal('show');                    
            }
        })
    } else {
        $('#pedidoModal').modal('show');    
    }
}
```

### Tentativas:

```
$('#cadastroModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', null);

$('#cadastroModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', undefined);
```

Comment: .off http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para cada `.on()` existe um `.off()`.

A [descrição da API do off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) é:

> *(original) The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on().*
>   (traduzido) **O método .off() remove ocscultadores de evento criados com .on().**

É importante referir a mesma função no momento do `.off()`. Eu sugiro mudar o seu código. Em vez de ter assim:

```
$('#cadastroModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // retorna ao comportamento anterior, só precisávamos agora
    $('#cadastroModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {});
    if (self.hasLoggedUser()) {
        $('#pedidoModal').modal('show');                    
    }
})
```

deve usar assim:

```
function handler(e) {
    // retorna ao comportamento anterior, só precisávamos agora
    $('#cadastroModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {});
    if (self.hasLoggedUser()) {
        $('#pedidoModal').modal('show');                    
    }
}

$('#cadastroModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', handler);
```

e quando se quiser remover, usar

```
$('#cadastroModal').off('hidden.bs.modal', handler);
```

Se não se indicar a mesma função (e funções anónimas não se poder referir) o que acontece é que ele remove **todos** os event handlers para esse elemento.

Comment: Obrigado! Eu pesquisei pelas palavras erradas

Comment: @Caputo se a minha resposta resolveu a sua dúvida pode clicar para aceitar a resposta.

Comment: Desculpe pela demora em aceitar, acabei voltando ao site só hoje.